# Print report without dialogbox

Tags: crystal-reports, ole, powerbuilder

My `PrintReport` funtion works, but I want to print the report directly from PowerBuilder to the default printer *without* creating a dialog box. How can I accomplish this? Also can I specify a page range at the same time?

I use Crystal Reports 11.5 and PowerBuilder 12.5.

Answer (score 0):

PowerBuilder does not have a 'PrintReport' method.  Not sure if this is something in your application code or in Crystal.  If you are printing a datawindow, you can check the Print Specifications - Prompt Before Printing option.

Comment: For Crystal Reports in PowerBuilder i am using OleObject and use ConnectToNewObject for CrystalRuntime.Application. Connection is successful and report is viewed. There is print button in the default toolbar that comes with the embedded report viewer. That toolbar button works fine and opens the dialog box to select the printer and send print to the selected printer. I wanted to print the report without the print dialogbox. I found solution to this problem. Only 133 character are left so i need to post detail in answer section of this page.

Comment: The PrintReport is the method for insertable crystal reports ActiveX control. It wont work with PowerBuilder without the ActiveX control. There is another problem i amtrying to solve. How i can get total number of pages of a crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

1- Declare instance variables in the window you are working

```
String module
String Folder,  FileName
Datawindow theDw

OLEObject g_ole_crx_application
OLEObject g_ole_crx_report
OLEObject g_ole_crx_connection_info
OLEObject g_ole_crx_export_options
OLEObject g_ole_crx_report_controls

String gs_rpt_filename, queryString, report_folder, report_file

OLEObject myoleobject

Long gi_return

//Please remove those variables you dont need
```

---

2- Paste following in any control (for example button)

```
String LoadFrom, LoadFile="C:\BT\SVN\Crystal\PB\app_reports_by_company_module.rpt" 
Integer Object_Id

g_ole_crx_application = CREATE OLEObject

gi_return  = g_ole_crx_application.ConnectToNewObject('CrystalDesignRunTime.Application.11')

if gi_return < 0 then

      MessageBox("Error", "Not connected to Crystal report")
      return

else

      gs_rpt_filename = LoadFile
      g_ole_crx_report = g_ole_crx_application.OpenReport(gs_rpt_filename) 

//Returns 0 if the report file does not exist or if an error occurs.

end if

queryString = g_ole_crx_report.ApplicationName  
g_ole_crx_connection_info =
g_ole_crx_report.database.tables[1].ConnectionProperties 
g_ole_crx_connection_info.deleteAll 


//g_ole_crx_report_controls = g_ole_crx_report.PageGenerator.Pages

String ConnectInfo = ""

//after deleting connection properties , add new connection properties
g_ole_crx_connection_info.add("Data Source", SQLCA.ServerName)
g_ole_crx_connection_info.add("Initial Catalog", SQLCA.Database)
g_ole_crx_connection_info.add("Database Type", "OLE DB (ADO)")
g_ole_crx_connection_info.add("Provider", "SQLNCLI10")
g_ole_crx_connection_info.add("User ID", SQLCA.logid)
g_ole_crx_connection_info.add("Password", SQLCA.logpass)
ConnectInfo += "Provider='SQLNCLI10';Data Source='"  + SQLCA.ServerName + "';"
ConnectInfo += "Initial Catalog='" + SQLCA.Database + "';DatabaseType='OLE DB (ADO)';"
ConnectInfo += "User ID=" + SQLCA.logid + ";Password=" + SQLCA.logpass
g_ole_crx_connection_info.add("ConnectInfo", ConnectInfo)

g_ole_crx_report.database.Verify 

//add parameters if there are any

//g_ole_crx_report.ParameterFields.GetItemByName("comp_code").AddCurrentValue('C001')

// here is the way how you can send print to the printer without print dialog box

// first set printer 

g_ole_crx_report.SelectPrinter("HP LaserJet 2200 Series PCL 5","HP LaserJet 2200 Series PCL 5", "LPT1")

// now use the PrintOut method 

g_ole_crx_report.PrintOut (FALSE, 1, TRUE, 1, 1)

// if you have insertable control to view crystal report you can use ReportSource and ViewReport

// i have it in a tab page with the name ole_view

// make sure you also set the source

//tab_1.tp_preview.ole_view.object.ReportSource(g_ole_crx_report)
//tab_1.tp_preview.ole_view.object.ViewReport



// Reference pdf : Crystal Reports XI Technical Reference Guide

// that will work hopefully
```

Comment: The PrintOut function in the above code sending just first page to the printer(the last two parameters 1, 1) if lets say there are 3 pages i want to send to the printer then last two parameters of the function should be 1, 3. The syntax is : PrintOut ([promptUser], [numberOfCopy], [collated], 
[startPageN], [stopPageN])

Comment: Also note that the ConnectToNewObject function is connecting to ('CrystalDesignRunTime.Application.11'). CrystalDesignRunTime Is required for the PrintOut method.

Comment: Just updating: CrystalDesignRunTime is not required for PrintOut method. The method works with CrystalRuntime.Application.xx.